# Current Location updating not working in iphone Device

Tags: iphone, ios, currentlocation

Working on application that needs to update current location in every second.

for that i am using `CoreLocation` framework.

My code is like

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [locationManager retain];
}
```

and implementing it's Delegate methods

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
   CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    NSLog(@"New location is >>>>>> %@",locB);

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>> error :%@", [error description]);

}
```

My Problem is that when i am running this code into simulator then it's working fine and updating location every second but when i run it into device then it shows location updating 3 or 4 times only.

I need this code working in both iphone 4 & iphone 5.

I have not found any solution for that.

Actually i need to count distance or count steps..for that i can also accelerometer but it's not giving perfect solution.

Please Help...

Thanks !

Comment: hey use CLLocationManagerDelegate Protocol Reference for this .. :)

Comment: see this link dude.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516967/how-to-find-your-current-location-with-corelocation see the second answer from that..

Comment: you want to get the location in background mode also??

Comment: @ParasJoshi : sorry for late reply..i am using CLLocationManagerDelegate Protocol ???? I think i am using that one.

Comment: NO i dont want it in background.

Comment: Hello friends I found link http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5467 that says "GPS accuracy varies depending on the number of visible GPS satellites. Locating all visible satellites can take several minutes, with accuracy gradually increasing over time."   It means i can't update my location every second..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22057/discussion-between-paras-joshi-and-sarafaraz-babi)

Comment: see this answer dude.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866292/iphone-sdk-track-users-location-using-gps

Answer (score 1):

My impression that it does not update position all the time and only does it for 3-5 times in order to provide some number of alternatives that you can use to find the best one. Try to use [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] to re-start positions generation and  [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; to stop in in your tear down code.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply..I am using  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] but not working.

Comment: try to stop it before calling startUpdatingLocation ;)

Comment: Alternatively you could start updating, create background thread and with timing you need (1s) check for [location_manager location] property and ignore any updates sent to delegate. You could also save old position to later know if its changed. If changed - send a msg selector, whatever to main thread (important) to update your UI.

Comment: can i have any demo please.?b'coz can't understand what to do...it's quite simple thing and it should be run but creates problem...

Comment: sorry don't have time to create a demo. Search for some examples on this site. I remember I saw some of them.

Comment: I used this thing myself but not in a way you need. In my case I need position only once.

Comment: Hummm...if you wants position then it gives ones very fine...but location updates is based on GPS Settelite and it could take 1 min or 10 min also...so that's the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can not run the application in background. You have to register it as an app that runs in the background. See the section Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks in this Link

[ManagingYourApplicationsFlow](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3)

**UPDATE:**

See this answer

[iPhone SDK: Track users location using GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866292/iphone-sdk-track-users-location-using-gps)