# How to get users current location on app launch

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-location

I want to get users current location(lat,long) on the app launch only..i dont want to use delegate method for frequent location updates..I m not using maps just need current location on launch..how should i do this??

I am using the code below but its not working.

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate=self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

CLLocation *location;
location = [locationManager location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
coord.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
coord.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
NSLog(@"latitude %f longitude %f",coord.latitude,coord.longitude);
```

Output:-
latitude 0.000000 longitude 0.000000

please help..

Comment: hey u have to go trough delegate method to get current location of user

Comment: you have to use delegate medhods once the location is fetched you can stop the location updates from location manager

Comment: [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

Comment: thanks all..using delegate method for location and then using   [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation] to stop future updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better you use the delegate method to get user location and in didupdateLocation method stop it
 I think this url may help you
       [iPhone SDK: Track users location using GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866292/iphone-sdk-track-users-location-using-gps)
 and in

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
CLLocationCoordinate2D here =  newLocation.coordinate;
NSLog(@"%f  %f ", here.latitude, here.longitude);
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

and you done with it...

Answer (score 1):

Use `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"latitude %f longitude %f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude,,newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

}
```

Above method is deprecated in iOS6, use `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` instead

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    // NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    // Reverse Geocoding
    //  NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        //  NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get user location without using this delegate method.??

Comment: no it cant and according to this way delegate methods will called once  so it wont give extra load to app

Answer (score 0):

```
import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

delegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // System alert for Allowing current location of user.

    // Location manager object creation.
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];`enter code here`

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


// iOS >= 6.0.
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

// iOS < 6.0
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```